# Error en el INSERT a SQL Server

Tags: android-studio, sql-server

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con la estructura que tiene mi INSERT en SQL Server ya que me marca el siguiente error.
La conexión si la está haciendo bien.

> Metodo INSERT

```
public int registrar() {
        int ideVenta = 0;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();

        try {
            if (conn.conexionDB() == null) {
                Log.d("---------------------ACCESO", "Error de acceso");
            } else {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                Date date = new Date();
                String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);

                String query = "INSERT INTO Ventas values (0, 4011, '"+fecha+"', NULL, NULL, 'Abierta','Mayoreo',0,80.00,'Super Administrador',NULL,NULL,NULL)";
                st = conn.conexionDB().createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(query);

//                rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
//                ideVenta = rs.getInt(1);

                st.close();
                rs.close();
//                conn.close();

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Clase ClienteDaoImple, método registrar");
            e.printStackTrace();
            ideVenta = 0;
        }
        return ideVenta;
    }
```

> Error que manda

```
D/---------------------------------CONEXION: Muy bien
I/System.out: Error: Clase ClienteDaoImple, método registrar
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result set.
W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:516)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1427)
        at com.example.pegasso.DAO.VentasDaoImpl.registrar(VentasDaoImpl.java:40)
```

Comment: El error dice que ese tipo de instruccion (executeQuery) espera que la query retorne un resultset.. Como un insert no retorna nada, deberias usar otra funcion de esa clase (creo que es executeStatement)

Comment: Tienes algun ejemplo de como lo puedo hacer

Comment: Verifica la documentacion de la clase, ahi seguro esta cual es la que debes usar.

Comment: Usa executeQuery() con "SELECT" y executeUpdate() con INSERT, DELETE y UPDATE o execute() con cualquier tipo de operacion.

Comment: La respuesta es la que dice @Duston. Como sugerencia, no uses jTds que hace rato que está abandonado el proyecto y no es JDBC4. Usa el driver de MS

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result
>   set.

Se debe a que **estas realizando una inserción de información usando [executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String))** pero tu query no retorna un `ResultSet`.

> [executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) Ejecuta la instrucción SQL dada, que devuelve un
>   único objeto ResultSet.

**En lugar de usar [executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) usa [executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))**  :

```
   //rs = st.executeQuery(query);
   rs = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

---

> **[executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))** Ejecuta la instrucción SQL dada, que puede ser
>   una instrucción INSERT, UPDATE, o DELETE o una instrucción SQL que no
>   devuelve nada, como una instrucción DDL de SQL.

Comment: puede usar solo `st.execute(query);` de todas maneras mala idea usar la libreria de jtds, la use y no funciono como queria